# ERROR: 57014: canceling statement due to user request

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

I am trying to fill the data set with the postgres as backend. The stored procedure is used, the query is complex. But when I try to fill data set, this error occurs and the dataset is not filled:

> ERROR: 57014: canceling statement due to user request

Comment: Do you get this error immediately after invoking the query or after some time. It might just be some client-side timeout being set.

Comment: i get this error after some time.after i click on button .  If i run this Query on pgAdmin it return the result. but when i try through the code . this Come - Ancoron

Comment: we have use the NpgsqlDataAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the soluation.
actually we use the NpgsqlDataAdapter and which is disconnected oriented.
we remove it. and use the DataReader and its Execute reader method.
Data reader is read the row by row data from database and still hold the connection. and use client side buffer. which reduce the Network overhead and improve the application performance.
and also give the command time out.